# Is flash less secure now that it is End of Life?

Tags: windows, macos, flash

As of this month, the Flash player has been disabled from all mainstream browsers. However, several platforms are still offering ways to use Flash content, most notably the games hosted on said platforms.

**How (in-) secure is this method of using Flash? And especially how does this differ from last month?**

Considerations:

- The method of access may matter, let us assume one uses the latest version of their recommended player, not an old version of a regular browser.
- There must be multiple threat vectors, if the platform or content supplier has bad intent it is presumably completely insecure, but perhaps this was already the case before this month as well.
- It might or might not help if one had a way to not access any new content, but only content that was already created and accessed before this month.

I believe all major flash platforms did this: NewGrounds, Kongregate, Armorgames

I know Kongregate.com is pushing the SuperNova Flash player so let's focus on that if the platform matters for the answer.

Comment: *"... still offering ways to use Flash content ... How (in-) secure is __this__ method of using Flash? ..."* - and __this__ method is what exactly? There are no links or any other information so one can figure out what these __unspecific__ platforms you mention actually do.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Edited in an example

Comment: So, what is "this method"? You still don't explain that. SuperNova, in particular, or after-market Flash players?

Comment: Adobe Flash was insecure because of the player and its many vulnerabilities. You appear to be asking about the vulnerabilities of an undisclosed/unmentioned player. I'm not sure that we can answer that, even if you name one. It becomes, "how secure is player X?"

Comment: The main threat vector was malicious content. Since the platforms I'm aware of bundle their own copies of games, or download them from their own servers, not from random websites, this is significantly alleviated. Of course, it's possible that some malware got into the games collection.

Comment: "is flash less secure" Less secure than what? The reason it is being dropped from browsers is that it wasn't secure to begin with.

Comment: Accepted the answer as it adequately answered my question. Ironically it just got closed for being unanswerable, so I guess it was clear for some but not for others. Will leave it closed as it is already answered anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**End of Life** means that Adobe will no longer provide any updates to it. That means if anyone (had already) found a vulnerability today, Adobe would not patch it - regardless of how critical it would be.

#### How much of a problem is this in practice?

How lucrative of a target Flash is becoming depends on how many people still cling to it - despite being told with brightly flashing red warning labels that they shouldn't. After all, even to this day, there are people running on Windows XP. Flash is, from a security point of view, in a relatively good position (compared to Windows XP), as there has been plenty of time for developers to switch to alternative options, such as HTML 5. Furthermore, Flash is rarely used for enterprise applications, and as such companies have very little incentive to keep Flash alive - which in turn makes it a less lucrative target for attackers.

#### What are the *actual* real life risks of using Flash?

That depends on the vulnerabilities being found. The more time passes, the more severe the vulnerabilities will become. Since the end of life period has barely begun and news articles of "the big Flash vulnerability" haven't flooded in yet, I would cautiously rate it as "probably not extremely dangerous yet". However, regularly using Flash even after end of life is just asking for trouble - as such, every security expert will recommend you not to use it.

#### What about third party Flash players?

Flash content is provided through a number of file formats, which are more or less publicly documented. Even while Adobe's Flash player was still actively maintained, other third-party projects like [Gnash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnash_(software)) were being developed, which sought to offer an open-source alternative to Adobe's proprietary software. In theory, it is possible to develop a feature-complete and secure flash player, but I doubt that this will ever happen.

The reason for this is the fact that Flash has lost all relevance. Nobody develops content for Flash anymore, outside from niche groups. As such, "keeping Flash alive" should be seen more as an archival project, similar to emulators for old video game consoles. After all, this too is history worth preserving.

#### Are third-party Flash players safe to use?

I don't know. Nobody can really know until these players have been audited to a satisfactory degree. If all you care about is occasionally playing your favourite old Flash games, then it will *probably* be fine to download the files and run them locally. If you aim to keep that one business application running that was developed in 1998 using Flash...then I would advise against that.